# C# Playing with generics, reflection and type inference

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm doing some experiments with generic types and I'm struggling to achieve what I'm looking for. I'm actually not sure that it's even possible to do that. Here's a sample :

```
public class Request { }
public class RequestTest : Request { }

public class Response { }
public class ResponseTest : Response { }

public abstract class Base
{
    // some stuff
}

public abstract class WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput> : Base
    where TInput : Request
    where TOutput : Response
{
    public abstract TOutput Execute();

    protected TInput Input { get; set; }
    protected TOutput Output { get; set; }

    public WebMethodBase(TInput input, TOutput output)
    {
        Input = input;
        Output = output;
    }
}

public class Test : WebMethodBase<RequestTest, ResponseTest>
{
    public override ResponseTest Execute()
    {
        // Do some treatment with the input
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        return Output;
    }

    public Test(RequestTest input, ResponseTest output) : base(input, output) { }
}

public static class WebMethodBaseHelper
{
    public static WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput> Create<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input, TOutput output)
        where TInput : Request
        where TOutput : Response    
    {
        Type baseType = typeof(WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput>);
        Type childType = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where((t) => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass).FirstOrDefault();
        var constructor = childType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TInput), typeof(TOutput) });
        return (WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput>)constructor.Invoke(new Object[] {input, output});
}

class Program
{
    private static TOutput Execute<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input, TOutput output)
        where TInput : Request
        where TOutput : Response 
    {
        WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput> webMethod = WebMethodBaseHelper.Create(input, output);
        return webMethod.Execute();
    }

    private static ResponseTest Run(RequestTest request)
    {
        return Execute(request, new ResponseTest());
    }

    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        ResponseTest result = Run(new RequestTest());
    }
}
```

This sample is working but it's unclear for anyone who would read that code which implementation of `WebMethodBase<>` is instanciated when you call the `Execute` method. What I'd like to achieve is to modify the `Execute` method to be able to call it this way inside the `Run` method :

```
return Execute<Test>(request);
```

Since the `Test` class is inheriting `WebMethodBase<>` I guess somehow we should be able to retrieve the generic types and make the whole function generic as well, but I'm not really sure that this is something possible. I tried a lot of different ways already and this is the closest implementation I was able to get from what I want.

Any help to achieve this or explanation of why this is not possible would be much appreciated.

Thanks

---

**Edit**

I'm able to get what I want by having the following :

```
private static TOutput Execute<TMethod, TInput, TOutput>(TInput input)
    where TMethod : WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput>
    where TInput : Request
    where TOutput : Response, new()
{
    TOutput output = new TOutput();
    var constructor = typeof(TMethod).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TInput), typeof(TOutput) });
    TMethod instance = (TMethod)constructor.Invoke(new Object[] { input, output });
    return instance.Execute();
}
```

And calling it this way :

```
return Execute<Test, RequestTest, ResponseTest>(request);
```

But I don't want to have to specify all three types each time I need to call the `Execute` method.

Comment: If it is unclear which one is constructed, can't you simply add a breakpoint to the constructors and see?

Comment: `request` doesn't exist in this line `return Execute(request, new ResponseTest());`, is `input` meant here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's unclear for another developer who would take a look at the calling code.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes indeed, I've edited the question

Comment: I think a worse issue here is that if there are multiple classes that implement `WebMethodBase<RequestTest, ResponseTest>`, one of those is arbitrarily selected and nobody ever knows about that. I'd much prefer a `Single` over `FirstOrDefault` there - especially because the following code assumes that the `First` part was successful and cannot cope with the `Default`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah I noticed that too and i completely agree with that. I know that sample is not bulletproof, I just made it this way as a proof of concept. That's also why I'd like to have a way to specify directly which implementation to use in the caller, but without having to specify all the 3 types needed.

Comment: IMO, it's better to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my issue. I wasn't really aware of the [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) concept and this helped me to achieve what I was looking for.
Below the changes I did to the sample I gave in the original question.

Added a covariant generic interface

```
public interface IWebMethodBase<out T1, out T2>
    where T1 : Request
    where T2 : Response
{
    T2 Execute();
}
```

Then modified the `WebMethodBase<>` class to implement this interface

```
public abstract class WebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput> : Base, IWebMethodBase<TInput, TOutput>
    where TInput : Request
    where TOutput : Response
{
    public abstract TOutput Execute();

    protected TInput Input { get; set; }

    public WebMethodBase(TInput input)
    {
        Input = input;
    }
}
```

Changed as well the `Test` class which inherits of the one above to reflect its changes and finally the `Execute` method

```
public static Response Execute<T>(Request request)
{
    ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { request.GetType() });
    T instance = (T)constructor.Invoke(new Object[] { request });
    return instance.Execute();
}
```

And to call it

```
ResponseTest result = Execute<Test>(new RequestTest()) as ResponseTest;
```

Using this covariant interface allows the caller to use any generic type that inherits or derives from the applied constraint and make it work as I wanted.

The only thing that I tried to improve there is the needed cast from the final caller, but I didn't find any way to achieve this, apparently it's the compiler itself that refuses to implicitly cast the return value to its derived implementation. I know it's possible in `VB.Net` using `option strict off` which I don't recommend, but that's all.

If there's anyone with a better solution or improvements to make to mine, feel free to edit this answer.